# To show a subspace is dense in a normed linear space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a normed linear space and $B$ be a subspace of $A$. In order to show $B$ is dense in $A$ it is enough to show that for any $T\in A^*$(dual space of $A$), if $T$ vanishes on $B$ then $T$ is identically zero.

My questions:

1. Let $C$ be dense subspace of $A^*$. Then is the statement :
   "In order to show $B$ is dense in $A$ it is enough to show that for any $T\in C,$ if $T$ vanishes on $B$ then $T$ is identically zero" true?
2. If (1) is true then can it be generalized further in some sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the claim is false.

Let $A = \ell^2$ and let $B$ be the orthogonal complement of the sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_n$ in $\ell^2$. Then $A^* = \ell^2$ as well and set $C = c_{00}$, the subspace of all finitely-supported sequences.

Then $B$ is not dense in $A$, but for every $f \in C$ holds $f|_B = 0 \implies f=0$. Indeed, let $f =(\alpha_n)_n \in C$ be such that $f|_B=0$. For every $n\in\Bbb{N}$ we have that $$e_1-ne_n \perp \left(\frac1n\right)_n \implies e_1-ne_n \in B \implies f(e_1-ne_n) = 0 \implies \alpha_1 - n\alpha_n=0 \implies \alpha_n = \frac1n\alpha_1.$$
But if $\alpha_1 \ne 0$, we would have $\alpha_n \ne 0$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$ contradicting the fact that $f \in c_{00}$. Hence $\alpha_1 = 0$ and consequently $\alpha_n = 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Therefore $f=0$.